# &amp; is valid in an HTML attribute?

Tags: html

While writing a series of music options, he called me to attention as Atom expected me to close with a ; after putting a & in the value section.

```
<option value="R&amp;B/Soul">R&amp;B/Soul</option>
<option value="R&B/Soul">R&amp;B/Soul</option>
```

Is the first line correct, or is it just an atom error?

Comment: Of course it is valid;  dont let you bully by freaky rules in editors.

Comment: It is valid, as @BoltClock pointed out. Here's another reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes, it's correct.](https://checker.html5.org/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%3Ctitle%3E%26amp%3Bamp%3B+in+attribute+value%3C%2Ftitle%3E%250A%3Cselect%3E%3Coption+value%3D%22R%26amp%3BB%2FSoul%22%3ER%26amp%3BB%2FSoul%3C%2Foption%3E%3C%2Fselect%3E)<sup>1</sup> It's pretty clear that you did in fact terminate the character reference with a ; in the right spot, so I don't know why Atom is complaining.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In fact, [both lines are valid](https://checker.html5.org/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%3Ctitle%3E%26amp%3Bamp%3B+in+attribute+value%3C%2Ftitle%3E%250A%3Cselect%3E%250A%3Coption+value%3D%22R%26amp%3BB%2FSoul%22%3ER%26amp%3BB%2FSoul%3C%2Foption%3E%250A%3Coption+value%3D%22R%26B%2FSoul%22%3ER%26amp%3BB%2FSoul%3C%2Foption%3E%250A%3C%2Fselect%3E), even if the latter is incredibly bad practice.</sub>